# Why is index.cgi displayed as content instead of being executed?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, linuxmint

I am trying to make a site with index.cgi, if available, served up as the content. In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default, I have:

```
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/mirror
```

The DocumentRoot is given +ExecCGI:

```
            Options +ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

When I visit localhost, it displays the source of index.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
if ($ENV{"HTTP_HOST"} =~ /^www\./)
    {
    print "Status: 301 Moved Permanently\n";
    print "Location: http://" . substr($ENV{"HTTP_HOST"}, 4) . "\n\n";
    }
if ($ENV{"HTTP_HOST"} =~ /^fan/ or $ENV{"HTTP_HOST"} =~ /jonathanscommunity/)
    {
    print "Status: 301 Moved Permanently\n";
    print "Location: http://www.facebook.com/pages/CJS-Hayward/9506801167\n\n";
...
```

What do I need to do so the /index.cgi is executed and its results given?

Comment: I also gave "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi". It still displays the source.

Comment: And now it's giving a "permission denied" error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is an answer that is probably correct, but the question has been abandoned by its owner so there is no way of knowing.

Comment: "there is an answer that is probably correct" -- I was the author of the answer and I still lost some points by having that deleted. #WTF?